# Remove entry from Map if object meets certain criteria

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map of objects, and I want to delete it from the map if the objects attributes meet a certain criteria.

The map is as follows

```
Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem> under20 = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"), new TypeReference<Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem>>() {});
```

Each ExchangeSummary has a sell_average, sell_quantity, and buy_quantity, and I want to remove it from the map if sell_average > 2000, and buy/sell quantities are both 0.

My current code is as follows but doesn't successful remove any values from the map (the map still had the same size)

```
for (ExchangeSummaryItem item : under20.values()) {
     int ObjSellAverage = item.getSellAverage();
     int ObjSellQ = item.getSellQuantity();
     int ObjBuyQ = item.getBuyQuantity();

     if (ObjSellAverage > 20000 && ObjSellQ == 0 && ObjBuyQ == 0){
          System.out.println(under20.size());
          under20.remove(item);
     }
}
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be much appreciated! Thank-you!

Comment: `under20.remove(item);` is calling `remove` with the value. It expects the *key*.

Comment: @ernest_k Is there a function to get the key of item so I can then remove it?

Comment: @ernest_k I tried adding ```i++;``` to the for loop and then used ```under20.remove(i);``` with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`under20.remove(item);` is calling `remove` with the value. It expects the *key*.
You also can't just change to iterating over `under20.keySet()` and calling `remove`, because you'd have a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

One easy way to solve it is to create another map:

```
Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem> result = new HashMap<>();

//Map.entrySet() gives you access to both key and value.
for (Map.Entry<String,ExchangeSummaryItem> item : under20.entrySet()) {
     int ObjSellAverage = item.getValue().getSellAverage();
     int ObjSellQ = item.getValue().getSellQuantity();
     int ObjBuyQ = item.getValue().getBuyQuantity();

     if (!(ObjSellAverage > 20000 && ObjSellQ == 0 && ObjBuyQ == 0)){
          result.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
     }
}
```

And use filtered values in `result`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ernest! I am getting this Type mismatch on the line with the for loop ```Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<String,ExchangeSummaryItem> to ExchangeSummaryItem``` which is then leading to ```getValue()``` and ```getKey``` being undefined.

Comment: @JacobWindolf Opps sorry. Edited.

Comment: and when I change it to ```for (Entry<String, ExchangeSummaryItem> item : under20.entrySet()) {``` the map is the same size as before

Comment: @JacobWindolf Yes, I didn't `remove` from `under20`. As noted in the answer, use `result`, it will have the correct entries only.